# Fallback for mathcal unicode characters in lualatex with proper height

Tags: luatex, fontspec, newunicodechar

Very few monospace fonts support unicode characters like U+1D4AA (Mathematical Script Capital O). I'm using DejaVu Sans Mono, and I'd like to define a fallback. Right now I have this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\newunicodechar{}{$\mathcal{O}$}
\begin{document}
Aa\texttt{AaA}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: AaAaOA]

I'd like the O to be the same size as the monospaced A (but keeping the height of the monospaced a the same as the body text a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing any OpenType font with the Computer Modern calligraphic letters. With Latin Modern Math you get a similar glyph. Anyway, I'm afraid you need to compute the scale factor yourself.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\newfontface{\calligraphic}{Latin Modern Math}[Scale=0.85]
\newunicodechar{}{{\normalfont\calligraphic }}

\begin{document}

Aa\texttt{AaA}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you elaborate why it's an issue in this case? I'd like to understand this. We're dealing with a true unicode character, not trying to make a font change.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, got it. Thanks! This is just a minimal example. I'm using it to typeset Julia code that has some unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[Scale=0.85,range="1D4AA]{XITS Math}
\newunicodechar{}{$\symcal{O}$}
\begin{document}
    Aa\texttt{AaA}\tiny Aa\texttt{AaA}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's definitely the desired effect! Does there happen to be a way to do it without using the unicode-math package?

Comment: Yes, you can define your own virtual font, but that is more work than using `unicode-math` which itself should already be loaded if someone uses `xelatex` or `lualatex`